# How to declare OpenUI5 (SAPUI5) components in html and do data binding in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sapui5

It is simple to instance SAPUI5/OpenUI5 component as JavaScript variable and to assign its content to the div in html page. But is there some way how to declare SAPUI5/OpenUI5 component in the html file - actually - the best place where the instance of the component should belong? I have read about Angular.js and OpenUI5 integration but this effort was not continued. It is time consuming to write so much JavaScript code where the other frameworks use HTML tags.

Comment: Actually the best place is the `JS` code...google single page web applications.  But if you really want to use `html` or `xml` you can create different types of `SAPUI5` views the options are: `Javascript` `XML` `HTML` and `JSON`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can write Views in `XML`, `HTML`, `JSON` and `JavaScript`. The corresponding Controller is always `JavaScript`.

Unlike `angular.js`, `SAPUI5`/`OpenUI5` doesn't enhance the existing `HTML` but takes the Control definitions from the view and creates the DOM based on it (in the Control Renderers). Therefore the "language" of the view only changes the parsing function.

Based on the [OpenUI5 Best Practices](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/tdg/index.html?responderOn=true), the [Explored App demoing the Controls](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html), the [Developer Guide](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/31a8db9d97544bb7964a6bf18e4678ef.html) (and my personal experience) SAP recommends using `XML` to create Views.

JavaScript Views might seem more powerful at first because you can include more logic in them. But that is also their biggest problem: By including logic in the View, you weaken the separation between View and Controller.

From my experience, declaring your Views in `XML` also makes them shorter (and more readable) compared to any other option.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the best place is the `JS code`...google single page web applications. But if you really want to use `html` or `xml` you can create different types of `SAPUI5` views the options are: `Javascript` `XML` `HTML` and `JSON`.

`SAP` recommends using the `Javascript` views/controllers they are more powerful.

Comment: "SAP recommends..." and indeed the developers see it as the good practice? To write JS not HTML tags?

Comment: As an OpenUI5 developer, I recommend using XML views as they help you create applications using MVC, while with JSViews, even I tend to mix view and controller code...

Comment: @sirion I also develop SAPUI5 apps. I would not recommend `XML Views` I would recommend `Javascript`. With `Javascript` you still have the `MVC` model there is a `Javascript View` and a `Javascript Controller` and you have more flexibility and control with `Javascript Views/Controllers`. However this question will draw very opinionated answers it is really up to the developer to decide what they like best...

Comment: Even though this is my private account and I am thus not speaking for my company, I would like to know where you got the info that SAP recommends using JSViews. All the documentation we wrote in the last two year focuses on XMLViews for the simple reason that it helps build easier to maintin MVC apps, see for example the Best Practices "Building" section: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/5ca68e6e62e6464a8103297fbc19cd9c.html. In the next version, there is a walkthrough that also uses XML: https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db.html

Comment: @sirion an SAPUI5 class from `SAP` - `SAPX05 SAP SAPUI5 User Experience Dev` I took it within the last year and the professor is the one that recommended to use `Javascript Views` even if he didn't recommend that I prefer `Javascript Views` to the other views as you have more control and flexibility and you can still keep your `MVC` model.

Comment: @sirion like I said it is a question that will draw very opinionated answers as different developers have different styles.  There isn't a correct answer to this question...

Comment: I almost forgot: The explored app (where all new controls are documented) uses exclusively XML examples: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85475/discussion-between-sirion-and-brso05).

Comment: As such SAP does not recommend you to use any type of view. It has already given us the flexibility to use any type of view depending on our comfort html/js/xml/json. XML views are easy to use and less verbose. JavaScript views give us the complete control where we can do everything.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to wrap the Angular js code as a OpenUI5 Component. You can use this Component any where in the openui5 application depending on the requirement.

This way the dependencies can be managed effectively and the code is modular. You can still have views and controllers within that.

........